# TypeError: _Model2.default.aggregate(...).forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cursor

When I am trying to iterate over the cursor I am getting following error

```
TypeError: _challengeModel2.default.aggregate(...).forEach is not a function
```

and here is my query

```
const completed = Challenge.aggregate([]).toArray()
```

can anyone please help me solve this and briefly explain about the cursor in mongodb

I am using **mongoose 5.x** and **mongodb 4.0**

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert the aggregation pipeline to an array but you can write it in this way:

```html
const completed = Challenge.aggregate([],(err,results) =>{
console.log(results)
})
```